# mediaelement.js streaming audio ie11 invalid source

Tags: audio, internet-explorer-11, mediaelement.js

I am trying to get MediaElement.js to work as a streaming mp3/radio player, and the test code works perfectly with Chrome and FireFox, but gives me an "Invalid Source" error when using it on IE11. I have an older flash only player that works in IE sorta, but doesn't at all in Android, and is otherwise old and a pain, so I want to update it. I have looked all over and seen a number of problems, but no clear solutions that I can implement. My code is bonehead simple, so I don't understand why this is happening, some seem to have worked around it, others seem stymied, but I haven't found a clear workaround. Any clues? How do I get a player to work in IE 11?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>mediaelement.js shoutcast example</title>
    <script src="../build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../build/css/mediaelementplayer.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br><br><center>
<audio id="player" width="100%" controls preload="metadata">
    <source src="http://s6.voscast.com:8166/;stream/1" data-plugin-type="flash" type="audio/mp3" />
    <source src="http://s6.voscast.com:8166/;stream/1" data-plugin-type="native" type="application/vnd.apple.mpegURL" />
</audio></center>

<script>var player = new MediaElementPlayer("#player", {mode: 'auto_plugin', pauseOtherPlayers: true, pluginPath: "js/", features: ["playpause", "volume", "current", "progress", "duration"] });</script>

</body>
</html>
```